# How do I define and load a resource in a Visual C++ project?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, resources

The code below compiles and runs.  When I debug it, however, the resource is NULL and the size is zero.  I imported "Resources\title.display.png" using the wizard, so I have to believe the path to the image is right.  No error is thrown.  These are the three files that comprise the project.  I have wittled it down to this and can't figure out what has gone wrong.  Any iseas?

sample.rc:

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "winres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""winres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// PNG
//

IDB_PNG1                PNG                     "Resources\\title.display.png"

#endif    // English (United States) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

resource.h:

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by sample.rc
//
#define IDB_PNG1                        101

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        102
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         40001
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1001
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

sample.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HMODULE module = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    HRSRC resource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1), RT_RCDATA);
    int resource_size = SizeofResource(module, resource);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing your image resource as a `PNG` resource, not an `RCDATA` resource.  As such, when calling `FindResource()`, you need to change `RT_RCDATA` to `TEXT("PNG")`:

```cpp
HRSRC resource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1), TEXT("PNG"));
```

Answer (score 2):

RT_DATA should have been L"PNG".

Comment: Yes, just figured that out.

Comment: Do you u mean `RT_RCDATA ` instead of `RT_DATA `?